# Hover over button

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want to make a shape in gosu to have a border when a mouse hovers over it.

```
Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
```

I expect the output, the shape will have a black border around it when the mouse cursor hovers over the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in `update` routine.

```
def update
  if mouse_over?(50, 50, 150, 100)
    Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
  end
end

  def mouse_over?(px1, py1, px2, py2)
    mx = mouse_x
    my = mouse_y

    ((mx >= px1) && (my >= py1)) && (mx <= px2) && (my <= py2)
  end
```

`mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are variable provided by Gosu.

[HERE MORE INFO...](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu/Window#mouse_x-instance_method)